# Check if React component is empty or has no child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I check if a React component is empty or has no child component? For example if I have a component called Component A, how can I check if it contains Component B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `this.props.children` to get any child components. If there is only one child, `this.props.children` will point to that child component, otherwise it will return an array of child components.

If its an array, you can use `this.props.children.map` to loop through them, and you can find the name, or type of the component like so:

```
this.props.children.map(child => console.log(child.type))
```